# Formula to read value rather than the formula in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA I'm trying to find a cell value in a certain sheet, but this sheet only has formulas.
How can I search the values instead of the formulas?
name1 is a variable

```
Set Var1= Range("E1:E9999").Find(name1)
If Var1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Name not Found!!!"
Else
    MsgBox Var1.Address
    MsgBox Var1.Value
End If
```

This way always return Name not Found!!!
Is there a way to search the values intead of the formulas?

Comment: When using `Find`, always specify the `What`, `LookIn`, and `LookAt` parameters.

Comment: If looping `Application.Match` would be quicker to return the row number:  https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

Comment: `.Find(name1, lookin:=xlValues)`

Answer (score -1):

.Find(name1, lookin:=xlValues)
Thanks k1dr0ck

Comment: See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), in particular  _The settings for LookIn, LookAt, SearchOrder, and MatchByte are saved each time you use this method. If you don't specify values for these arguments the next time you call the method, the saved values are used_.  Used in this context means either the user or vba.  So settings made by the user affect vba, and vice versa